# Why doesn't margin work inside divs?

Tags: css, parallax

I'm working on my first parallax page and I found a simple example over at [callmenick](http://callmenick.com/2014/07/15/simple-parallax-scrolling-effect/).

He has set his `parallax.section` to be 600px high. This is also the container for the images.

```
<section class="module content">
  <div class="container">    
    <h2>Lorem Ipsum Dolor</h2>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit...</p>
  </div>
</section>

<section class="module parallax parallax-2">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="test">Test container</div>
    <h1>Rise</h1>
  </div>
</section>
```

I've added a `test` div inside the `container` div with `margin-top: 30px;` I expected that it would create a 30 px margin between my test div and the container div. Instead it creates a gap between the section divs. Why is that?

If I add `overflow: hidden` to the `container` div, I solve this problem. But I still don't understand why margins don't work inside other divs.

You can [see my fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/4025qddu/2/).

The css used is this:

```
section.module.parallax {
  height: 600px;
  background-position: 50% 50%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-size: cover;
}

section.module .test{
    margin-top: 40px;
    background-color: #BCEF2F;
}
```

Comment: Because you are giving a margin in the div and get out the box. Maybe you want to use padding.

Comment: Yes, this creates the gap. What do you expect?

Comment: You set a 40px margin and want to know why there's a 40px space above the div? I don't follow.

Comment: Because the test div is inside `container` div and I expect there to be a gap between my `test` div and the `container` div. Not a gap between the `section` divs.

Comment: You mean like this http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/h5zs32x9/?

Comment: Yeah, I just tested that myself. But why isn't margin working inside divs?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're seeing [collapsing margins](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/margin_collapsing). To fix it add `overflow:auto` to your container div:

```
.container {
    max-width: 960px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    overflow:auto;
}
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/h5zs32x9/)**

Comment: Huh, I've never heard about collapsing margins, thanks. U learn something new every day :)